# Is there a better way to call a child function from a parent component in React, other than this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I tried to call a function in a child component from a parent component in React, but without the use of refs, and i succeeded but i don't know if my way is something other than a cheap hack. What can be a better way to do this?

I'm also reading the docs but i may have missed the right way. Any resource suggestion and idea is appreciated.

My parent code:

```
function Parent(props){ 
  const [submitClicked, setSubmitClicked] = useState(false);
  function onSubmitClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitClicked(true);
  }

  return (
    <Child 
      submitClicked={submitClicked}
      setSubmitClicked={setSubmitClicked}
    />
  );
}
```

Child code:

```
function Child(props) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(props.submitClicked){

      //do something in the child component...

      props.setSubmitClicked(false);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I will try to do it as you described and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass down a handler (a function) to the child component from the parent that deals with the state updates.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Child receives the handler
// When the button is clicked call the handler
function Child({ handleSubmit }) {
  return <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click me</button>
}

function Parent() {

  const [ submitClicked, setSubmitClicked ] = useState(0);

  // The handler deals with the state update
  function handleSubmit() {
    setSubmitClicked(submitClicked + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{submitClicked}</p>
      <Child handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This is other way around the question is how to call child function now parent function.